# how to build website with multiple pages and a single page app?

Tags: express, vue.js

I'm building an SPA with vuejs on the frontend and express on the backend, but what I want to know is how I'd combine a traditional static website with pages, along with an SPA.

So for example i want to have a landing page, static pages such as pricing, info, contact and so on, then when the user logs in they get redirected to /dashboard, and from here its an SPA.

It's probably a really stupid question but I honestly can't figure it out - do I need to host these seperately and only have the vue router start from /dashboard?

Comment: Create your website the 'traditional way' and only add the `<div id="app"></div>` element with it's javascript on your dashboard page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely no need to host it separately. All you need to do is to create your multipage static app in a traditional way. Next, simply build the SPA and run production build. This will generate index.html with all the javascript included. Then simply take this index.html, rename it if you want and put it under the desired path.